# How to execute code only once in a specific cell in tableView ( under a dequeueReusableCell)

Tags: swift

I want to change the Y position of a nested view in a particular cell in `viewTable`.

Let's say

```
let condition = myarray[indexPath.row]
if condition != nil  {                
    cell.myView.frame.origin.y += 15
}
```

The problem is that since this is under `dequeueReusableCell` every time you scroll it will execute the the code and add another 15 to the previous y position.

What is the best and correct way to execute this once for each cell?

Comment: Use a subclass of UITableViewCell and override the initializer.

Comment: @deadbeef, thanks would you give an example please, haven't done that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Declare a property `defaultViewY`

  ```
  var defaultViewY : CGFloat = 0.0
  ```
- In `viewDidLoad` get the default y-position of the view

  ```
  func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      defaultViewY = // add code to get the default y-position or use a literal constant
  }
  ```
- In `cellForRow` don't use the `+=` operator and add an `else` clause to *reset* the y-position if the condition is false

  ```
  let condition = myarray[indexPath.row]
  if condition != nil  {
      cell.myView.frame.origin.y = defaultViewY + 15.0
  } else {
      cell.myView.frame.origin.y = defaultViewY
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks , is that a "==" or "=" cause it gives me a warning that the result of "==" is unused. can you explain the reason of getting the viewWidth? trying to figure out the trick behind it.

Comment: My bad I updated the answer. I mean the default y-position rather than the width.

Comment: Thanks, instead of code under viewDidLoad I added the following code in the tableView func `if defultValueofY == 0.0 { defultValueofY = cell.myview.frame.origin.y }` things are looking good now cheers.